# How to add prefix in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Currently I've Custom Components in `/` prefix. I want to store all Custom Components in another prefix. Here's how I tried to create a prefix.

[image]

but nothing appears under `qml.qrc`

Comment: What do you mean by prefix? You mean every time you want to use `PathButton`, you want to instead use `MyPrefix.PathButton`?

Comment: @JarMan, right now I've `import "Components"` on my `main.qml` and with that I can use `PathButton` without any prefix. If I add a prefix I think I'd have to change that import statement to `import "MyPrefix/Components"`  BUT I'm not sure whether that'd work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your qml.qrc file in a text editor and you should see something like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Components/PathButton.qml</file>
        ...
```

Change that to this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/MyPrefix/">
        <file>Components/PathButton.qml</file>
        ...
```

Now you will have to use `import "MyPrefix/Components` in your qml file.

Comment: The way I used to create the `prefix` actually creates `prefix` BUT it doesn't appear there for some reason! When I open the `qml.qrc` with `Resource Editor` it shows the prefix there.